# 'No suitable constructor found for entity type' when doing EF Core migration (SmartEnum)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am attempting to run `update-database` to migrate some changes that I made to my db.

It all goes well until I get the following error:

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'ReportType'. The
>   following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to
>   properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'id', 'name' in
>   'ReportType(string id, string name)'.

Here is the code for ReportType.cs:

```
public class ReportType : SmartEnum<ReportType, string>
    {
        public static readonly ReportType ReportType1 = new ReportType("Blah", "Blah");
        public static readonly ReportType ReportType2 = new ReportType("Blah", "Blah");
        public static readonly ReportType ReportType3 = new ReportType("Blah", "Blah");

        // required for EF, but breaking for SmartEnum
        // private ReportType() {}

        private ReportType(string id, string name) : base(name, id)
        {

        }
    }
```

As you can see in the commented section of that code, having a parameterless constructor would normally fix this issue for EF Core, but SmartEnum doesn't have a parameterless constructor base.

There was a commit to the SmartEnum library on Arpil 27th, 2018 that added a parameterless constructor so that this issue wouldn't exist, but that change was removed in a later commit and I am unsure how to proceed without it.

That commit can be found here: https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum/commit/870012d406609a4a8889fdde2139750dc618d6a9

And was removed in this commit:
https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum/commit/1c9bf3ede229fcb561330719cd13af67dcf92ad7

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's my solution to this issue as per Ivan's comments:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
                .Property(p => p.ReportType)
                .HasConversion(
                    p => p.Value,
                    p =>ReportType.FromValue(p));
```

Comment: See [SmartEnum - 
Persisting with EF Core 2.1 or higher](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum#persisting-with-ef-core-21-or-higher). You are supposed to configure [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) for your "smart enum" type properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev What would that look like using my example?

Comment: You haven't shown an entity class having property of type `ReportType`. As you can see from the link, the value converter has to be setup per concrete property of a concrete entity type.

Comment: Ah, I see. Based on that last comment and your links, I'd say I have this figured out. I will edit in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnModelCreating of ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
            .Property(p => p.ReportType)
            .HasConversion(
                p => p.Value,
                p =>ReportType.FromValue(p));
```

Comment: I want to mention here, that you still need to have a parameterless constructor in order to work with EF Core, as per this issue [Issue #103](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum/issues/103)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor looks like this

```
 private ReportType(string id, string name) : base(name, id)
 {}
```

However, if you change it to

```
 private ReportType(string name, string value) : base(name, value)
 {}
```

It will work. Just tested it on my code.
EF core requires parameterless constructor, or a constructor with arguments for the confgiured properties (Name and Value).
The problem with your constructor is that you are supplying "id", but there is no such property in the base class. You need to pass "value"

Comment: *It will work* -- but it already did, as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: The accepted answer shows how to convert the complex enumeration type to an integer. I assume there is no DbSet for the ReportType in this case.
What I show is if you have the ReportType also as DbSet

Comment: Isn't this approach problematic, because you don't want to actually create a new instance?  You want to return the existing static instance for the given name.